# Extracting Strings of Data from a .txt file

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

When I input a file and try to extract the printed strings and doubles from it, I end up extracting information on the text itself. I inserted a System.out.println into my while loop to print the lines from the file, and it also printed extra lines of text information. I'm trying to get only the written text from the file, ignoring the lines that look like:

\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural"

I'm doing this so I can take the information from the file to make string arrays with them. 
The purpose of this program will be to input a file with rows of information (last name(string), first name(string), account balance(double)), extract each row separately, place each row string in an Array List, sort the array list (by last name then by first name), then output a file, with the name output.txt, with the new sorted rows. The rows will be formatted last name, first name, then account balance with a single space between each. The number of rows can vary.

Input example (from a .txt file):

Smith Charles 200.000

Allen Drake 5000.00

Allen Trey 300.00

Burbis Zeik 400.00

Zan Rick 6000.00

Output example (written to a file output.txt):

Allen Drake 5000.00

Allen Trey 300.00

Burbis Zeik 400.00

Smith Charles 200.000

Zan Rick 6000.00

Thanks!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner fileName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String file = fileName.next();
    String input;
      Scanner fileinput = null;
   // File inFile = new File("c:\\csc2310\\test.txt");
      File inFile = new File(file);
     int i = 0;
      try
      {
        fileinput = new Scanner(inFile);
        while(fileinput.hasNext())
        {

           i++;
           System.out.println(i);
           input = fileinput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        fileinput.close();
      }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
      }
      finally
      {
          fileinput.close();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Show us your input and your expected output please.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do, but, perhaps your problem is that you're using `println` instead of `print`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please edit your post and include some sample input and output.

Comment: I just updated my post. Hopefully, it will help clarify what my problem is. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with the way that TextEdit (the Mac OS text editor) saves .text files. I wrote the same information into JEdit, and saved it with the same extension, and it eliminated all the lines of text information. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Your string is spoilt. Java while reading it will automatically pad the \ characters with \.

Hence you get

```
"\\pard\\tx720\\tx1440\\tx2160\\tx2880\\tx3600\\tx4320\\tx5040\\tx5760\\tx6480\\tx7200\\tx7920\\tx8640\\ql\\qnatural\\pardirnatural"
```

Only thing you might be able to possibly do is read the string as byte array and remove the byte equivalent of \ . Check if it is possible